# Notify Parent hasMany list when child changes its parent

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say i have a relationship Parent (1) <-> Child (0..n) and corresponding models

```
Zik.Node = DS.Model.extend({  
    id : DS.attr('number'),  
    name : DS.attr('string'),  
    leafs : DS.hasMany('Zik.Leaf', {key : 'leaf_ids'})  
});  
Zik.Leaf = DS.Model.extend({  
    id : DS.attr('number'),  
    name : DS.attr('string'),  
    node : DS.belongsTo('Zik.Node')  
});
```

At some point one Zik.Node(id=2) child Zik.Leaf changes relationship to another parent Zik.Node(id = 1). Now if Zik.Node observes its leafs it gets notified, but list of leafs is the same.

One option is to remove leaf from previous parent and add it to new parent:

```
oldParent.removeObject(leaf;        
newParent.get('leafs').pushObject(leaf)
```

but to that does not seem right. Maybe there is some other more automagical way to get this working.
I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kristaps_petersons/6g22X/11/ to illustrate my point. Two lines are commented out, to see how leaf lists changes remove them.